# How to pass user id to Laravel form

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page for editing users preferences (admin section). There I want to fetch user's id. The url for edit page is this http://localhost:8000/admin/editUser/27 so the id is 27.

These are the routes:

```
Route::get('admin/editUser/{id}', 'AdminController@editUser');

Route::post('changeRoleType', 'AdminController@changeRoleType');
```

and the form:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'changeRoleType', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

My question is: how can I get this user's id in controller? When I do something like this:

```
public function changeRoleType($id)
    {
        dd($id);
    }
```

i want it to display the id of that user. In this case that would be 27 (from the given link).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this :

```
Route::get('admin/editUser/{id}', 'AdminController@editUser');

Route::post('changeRoleType/{id}', 'AdminController@changeRoleType')->name('updateRole');

{!! Form::model($editRole,['route' => ['updateRole', $editRole->id],'method' => 'post']) !!}
```

**Note** : `$editRole` variable is example and which is pass with edit view

Comment: It says -  `Route [changeRoleType] not defined`

Comment: @harunB10 Let me check it

Comment: @harunB10 Please update your route and form tag same like my answer

Comment: @harunB10 and check it

Comment: Ok, it works now... I forgot to name the route with `name('updateRole')`. Thx a lot!

Comment: @harunB10 Ok glad to help

Answer (score 1):

The id should be in the request object. Assuming you are using Request.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function changeRoleType(Request $request, $id)
    {
        dd($request->id);
    }
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests

Answer (score 1):

try this: in your controller to display the edit page select that users data to `$user` and pass that variable to view

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

and in your view page do this

```
{{ Form::model($user, [
    'route' => ['changeRoleType', $user->id],
    'class' => '',
    'role' => 'form',
    'method' => 'PATCH'
    ]) }}
```

also since the method is `patch` change your route to

```
Route::patch('changeRoleType', 'AdminController@changeRoleType');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do **Two** things:

You need to pass the user id in the form's url.

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'changeRoleType/{{ $user->id }}', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

after in your **routes** section you need to add this:

```
Route::post('changeRoleType/{user}', 'AdminController@changeRoleType');
```

So the method in Controller must be like this:

```
public function changeRoleType($user)
{
     dd($user);
}
```

**OR**

First, you can create a hidden input inside your form, so you can pass the $id inside the controller.

```
 {{ Form::hidden('id', '{{$user->id}}') }}
```

And then in your method.

```
public function changeRoleType(Request $request)
{
     dd($request->id);
}
```

**Note:** You need to specify the Request in the top of your Controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `route` method and add a parameter to this route.

`routes.php` or `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/order/{id}', [
           'as' => 'order.show', 
           'uses' => 'OrderController@showOrderFromOrderhistory'
]);
```

Then in your link or form, you can link to this route with parameter:

```
route('order.show', ['id' => $order->id]) }}
```

So in your example it would be:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('%route_name%', ['%param_name%' => $variable]), 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```